# How to set the location of a child window but not in the center of the owner window in WPF [SOLVED!]

Tags: c#, wpf, location

Ok so I am developing a game of dice, I have the game window and a message window that opens when I need a dialog. I found how to make the message window appear in the center of it's owner with the WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner", the problem is that it hides the dice displayed in the game window and for some messages like "Congrats you have a series! You win 2500 points but your turn ends here" I'd really like for the player to be able to see his lucky and oh so rare series before he clicks the "end your turn" dialog button which will reset the dice display for the next player.

My question is, is there a way to set the child window location a little higher than it's owner's center without hardcoding it? I feel like if I hardcode it by giving a value to it's Top and Left attributes while my game window is set to CenterScreen, the message location inside the game window will change depending on the user's screen.

Since I found a way to recenter my "Home" window (I don't know how to call it in english...) as it's height resizes, I had hopes there was a way to do something similar with my message window... the thing is, this one doesn't resize so I can't use the method I found... Still, here is the method used for my "Home" window, maybe it'll help come up with an idea?

```
protected override void OnRenderSizeChanged(SizeChangedInfo sizeInfo)
        {
            base.OnRenderSizeChanged(sizeInfo);

            this.Top += (sizeInfo.PreviousSize.Height - sizeInfo.NewSize.Height) / 2;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I typically use logic like this make my message dialogs appear a bit higher on the screen than center by basing my math off the of the main application window.  The logic is a bit crude but it works for me.

I am able to take these coordinates and feed them into the function that shows the dialog.  If you are unable to control your dialogs that way, you could use logic like this in the dialog's `Loaded` event handler

```
var win  = Application.Current.MainWindow;                     
var left = win.Left + Math.Max(win.ActualWidth  / 2 - 100, 0);
var top  = win.Top + Math.Max(win.ActualHeight / 4 - 50,  0);
var loc  = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
```

Comment: Thanks Joe! I didn't do exactly like what you suggested, but you showed me the way!

Here's what I came up with:

`private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Top = Owner.Top + (Owner.ActualHeight/4 - this.ActualHeight/2);
            this.Left = Owner.Left + (Owner.ActualWidth/2 - this.ActualWidth/2);
        }`

Since my Message window had the game window set as it's owner, I could retrieve the size and location info I needed to place it accordingly to the game window's location, even if the player moves it! :D